# Modifying a Material UI List component with styled() in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to port a project from JavaScript to TypeScript and I'm struggling with a part of the code where a modified version of the Material UI's List component is created using style().
The problem I'm facing is that when I try to use it with a property "component", TypeScript complains about it saying there is no such property.
I guess I need to make some sort of type assertion but I'm not sure

The code is the following:

**The styled list**

```js
const StyledList = styled(List)<ListProps>({
  '& .MuiListItemButton-root': {
    paddingLeft: 24,
    paddingRight: 24,
  },
  '& .MuiListItemIcon-root': {
    minWidth: 0,
    marginRight: 16,
  },
  '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```

**Using it**

```js
<StyledList component="nav" disablePadding>
</StyledList>
```

**The error**

> Type '{ children: (Element | Element[])[]; component: string; disablePadding: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; disablePadding?: boolean | undefined; subheader?: ReactNode; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...> & MUIStyledCommonProps<...>'.
> Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; disablePadding?: boolean | undefined; subheader?: ReactNode; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...> & MUIStyledCommonProps<...>

Everything works fine if I remove the `component="nav"` but I'm wondering why it says that property doesn't exist if `List` component does have it. I guess styled() is giving me some different kind of object or I need to make TypeScript be aware of it.

Comment: Your error should be formatted as code, not a quotation. You need to mention which component library you are using. There are tons of material UI component libraries out there for ReactJS.

Comment: @VirajShah Sorry, I will fix the formating of the error and I had no idea there multiple component libraries for MUI, since I'm very new to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason typescript is yelling at you is because `component` prop is not defined in the `ListProps` interface. So just add it here is the code which you can use.

```
interface StyledListProps extends ListProps {
    component?: React.ElementType;
}

const StyledList = styled(List)<StyledListProps>({
    '& .MuiListItemButton-root': {
        paddingLeft: 24,
        paddingRight: 24,
    },
    '& .MuiListItemIcon-root': {
        minWidth: 0,
        marginRight: 16,
    },
    '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
        fontSize: 20,
    },
});
```

Comment: As always, you can use chatGPT to ask this question and it will give you the same answer. Just to save more of your time.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know it could be that reliable, but it's good to know. Also, I can't upvote your answer because it seems I don't have enough reputation, but I have marked it as accepted answer. Once again, thank you for your help!